# How to parse out two fields out of string using regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm trying to figure out how to use regex to parse out fields from a naming scheme. Basically, a way to go through a query string and pull out patterns based on the naming scheme.  In this case, there are two patterns to pull out which are the ID and the DIRECTION.

`DIRECTION` will always be either 1 or 2

`ID` can be any string that is allowed for file systems (e.g., alphanumeric - _ .)

Here is the basic framework I'm trying to code up:

```py
def function(query:str, naming_scheme:str):
    # stuff
    return (ID, DIRECTION)
```

Here is a query for naming scheme 1 (`naming_scheme_1`):

```py
naming_scheme_1 = "[ID]_R[DIRECTION].fastq.gz"
ID, DIRECTION = function("Kuwait_110_S59_R1.fastq.gz", naming_scheme_1)
#ID = "Kuwait_110_S59"
#DIRECTION = "1"

ID, DIRECTION = function("Kuwait_110_S59_R2.fastq.gz", naming_scheme_1)
#ID = "Kuwait_110_S59"
#DIRECTION = "2"
```

Here is a query for naming scheme 2 (`naming_scheme_2`):

```py
naming_scheme_2 = "[ID]_R[DIRECTION]_001.fastq.gz"
ID, DIRECTION = function("Kuwait_110_S59_R1_001.fastq.gz", naming_scheme_2)
#ID = "Kuwait_110_S59"
#DIRECTION = "1"

ID, DIRECTION = function("Kuwait_110_S59_R2_001.fastq.gz", naming_scheme_2)
#ID = "Kuwait_110_S59"
#DIRECTION = "2"
```

Here is a query for naming scheme 3 (`naming_scheme_3`):

```py
naming_scheme_3 = "barcode-[ID]_[DIRECTION].fq"

ID, DIRECTION = function("barcode-Kuwait_110_S59_1.fq", naming_scheme_3)
ID = "Kuwait_110_S59"
DIRECTION = "1"

ID, DIRECTION = function("barcode-Kuwait_110_S59_2.fq", naming_scheme_3)
ID = "Kuwait_110_S59"
DIRECTION = "2"
```

**How can I use regex (or similar) in Python to parse out fields in this context?**

My current method is to do a series of splitting events on a string which doesn't seem like the best option.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what exactly do you want to find? (other than parsing)

Comment: Apologies, it was not very clear at all the way I wrote it initially.  Please check again.

Comment: I understand that you want to parse the `query` using the `naming_scheme`. What are these naming schemes? Can they be totally arbitrary or there are some rules?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense and I didn't provide much clarity earlier.  I've updated the question with these details. Basically, ID is any alphanumeric string (along with . _ - characters) that are allowed for filenaming systems and DIRECTION is always going to be 1 or 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code:

```py
import re

def repl(match_object):
    inside_bracket = match_object.group(1)
    if inside_bracket == "DIRECTION":
        return r"(?P<DIRECTION>[12])"
    if inside_bracket == "ID":
        return r"(?P<ID>[-.\w]+)"

def function(query: str, naming_scheme: str):
    pattern = re.sub(r"\[(.*?)\]", repl, naming_scheme)
    match = re.match(pattern, query)
    return match["ID"], match["DIRECTION"]
```

**Explanation:**

The most important thing was converting your template into a regex pattern, I mean:

```
[ID]_R[DIRECTION].fastq.gz   -->  (?P<ID>[-\w]+)_R(?P<DIRECTION>[12]).fastq.gz
```

This is done with the help of `repl` function which is passed to the `re.sub`. In this function I used `\[(.*?)\]` as the pattern, it basically catches brackets and their content. When creating the pattern, I used your rules for *DIRECTION* and *ID*. `[DIRECTION]` changed to a named group `(?P<DIRECTION>[12])` which only accepts `1` and `2` and `[ID]` changed to `(?P<ID>[-.\w]+)` for filenames (assuming there is no space in the filename)

That's it. Now you have your pattern which includes two *named groups*. 1- ID  2- DIRECTION. They can be fetched with `match["ID"]` and `match["DIRECTION"]`

here is a test:

```py
tests = [
    ("Kuwait_110_S59_R1.fastq.gz", "[ID]_R[DIRECTION].fastq.gz"),
    ("Kuwait_110_S59_R1_001.fastq.gz", "[ID]_R[DIRECTION]_001.fastq.gz"),
    ("barcode-Kuwait_110_S59_1.fq", "barcode-[ID]_[DIRECTION].fq"),
]

for query, naming_scheme in tests:
    ID, DIRECTION = function(query, naming_scheme)
    print(ID, DIRECTION)
```

output:

```
Kuwait_110_S59 1
Kuwait_110_S59 1
Kuwait_110_S59 1
```

**note**: I just accounted happy cases, don't forget to raise exception if your template(query) is not in a good shape.

Comment: `The most important thing was converting your template into a regex pattern, I mean:` Thank you for the explanation! I was trying to do this but it just got so weird and complicated that I couldn't make any progress using regex creators.

Answer (score 2):

If your 3rd naming scheme actually is

```
naming_scheme_3 = "barcode-[ID]_[DIRECTION].fq"
```

Then the Python code

```
import re

def get_id_and_direction(query: str):
    matcher = re.match("^(?:barcode-)?(?P<ID>[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)_R?(?P<DIRECTION>[12])(?:\.fq|(?:_001)?\.fastq\.gz)$",query)
    if matcher:
        return (matcher.group('ID'), matcher.group('DIRECTION'))
    else:
        return ( None, None )

print(get_id_and_direction('Kuwait_110_S59_R1.fastq.gz'))
print(get_id_and_direction('Kuwait_110_S59_R2.fastq.gz'))
print(get_id_and_direction('Kuwait_110_S59_R1_001.fastq.gz'))
print(get_id_and_direction('Kuwait_110_S59_R2_001.fastq.gz'))
print(get_id_and_direction('barcode-Kuwait_110_S59_1.fq'))
print(get_id_and_direction('barcode-Kuwait_110_S59_2.fq'))
```

will give you ID and DIRECTION for all 3 naming schemes at once:

```
('Kuwait_110_S59', '1')
('Kuwait_110_S59', '2')
('Kuwait_110_S59', '1')
('Kuwait_110_S59', '2')
('Kuwait_110_S59', '1')
('Kuwait_110_S59', '2')
```

The regex `"^(?:barcode-)?(?P<ID>[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)_R?(?P<DIRECTION>[12])(?:\.fq|(?:_001)?\.fastq\.gz)$"` works as follows:

`^(?:barcode-)?` looks for an optional 'barcode-' at the beginning - the ? at the end makes the whole expression optional.

`(?P<ID>[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)` is the (named) group that picks up the ID made up of one or more alphanumeric or '.', '_', '-' characters.

`_R?` matches _R or just _ (the ? behind R makes the R optional) always following the ID.

`(?P<DIRECTION>[12])` the (named) group that picks up a 1 or a 2 - the direction

`(?:\.fq|(?:_001)?\.fastq\.gz)$` makes sure the string ends with either '.fq' or '_001.fastq.gz' or '.fastq.gz' the 3 possible endings in your 3 naming schemes

See the code in action here: https://onlinegdb.com/yD8WBaPNt

Hope that gets you going!

Comment: This is great but the pattern is hard-coded. Ideally OP wants these to work with arbitrary `query` and `naming_scheme` pair, not just those three examples in the question.

Comment: @S.B Yeah… I didn’t realize that, when I wrote my answer. Anyway… your answer already got my upvote. ;-) Don’t know why my comment “Really nice idea!” on your answer was deleted. Probably violated some community rule because it was not constructive enough…

Answer (score 1):

The reason the commenters asked for parameters is that you didn't give any rules.

For example, does the ID always contain 'string_3 characters_3 characters'?

Is direction always a single character? Is it even more refined? Is it always a single digit?

I've provided an answer, but without sufficient parameters, this may not help you very much. If the assumptions I outlined in the comments in the code are true, this will work out just fine. That being said, if it doesn't work, give up some rules your strings must follow.

```
import re

str1 = "Kuwait_110_S59_R1.fastq.gz"
str2 = "Kuwait_110_S59_R1_001.fastq.gz"
str3 = "barcode-Kuwait_110_S59_1.fq"
str4 = "bar-Kuwait Kuwait_295_235_622.fg"

# this assumes 
#   the first char that matters for ID is always capitalized
#   always 3 characters between the 1st & 2nd hyphen & after 2nd hyphen
#   that direction is always a single character

def gimme(str):
  # look for the single char before period
  ID = re.search("(.)(?=(\.))", str).group(1)
  # look a capital letter then for *_3_3 before _
  DIRECTION = re.search("([A-Z].*_.{3}_.{3})(?=(_))", str).group(1)
  return (ID, DIRECTION)

s1 = gimme(str1)
s2 = gimme(str2)
s3 = gimme(str3)
s4 = gimme(str4)

print(s1)
# ('1', 'Kuwait_110_S59')
print(s2)
# ('1', 'Kuwait_110_S59')
print(s3)
# ('1', 'Kuwait_110_S59')
print(s4)
# ('2', 'Kuwait Kuwait_295_235')
```

Comment: You are certainly right and there was not much clarity in my question.  I updated the question to address this.  Basically DIRECTION is either 1 or 2 and ID is any string that can be used by filenaming systems (e.g., alphanumeric _ - .).

Comment: As for the filename or ID, how might you further specify this? In one of your examples, you had `barcode` which was not part of the ID (from your question). Is a capital letter sufficient to delineate that? Does the function I provided work? (it satisfies the requires you provided so far.)